# How to make urxvt open link when clicked with Ctrl

Tags: configuration, rxvt

Currently urxvt recognizes links and underlines them. While clicked, it opens them in firefox. Here's my current .Xresources:

```
URxvt.perl-ext:           default,matcher
URxvt.url-launcher:       firefox
URxvt.matcher.button:     1
URxvt.matcher.pattern.1:  \\bwww\\.[\\w-]+\\.[\\w./?&@#-]*[\\w/-]
```

I want urxvt not to underline links by default. I want it to underline them only when mouse is over them. I also want urxvt to do nothing when their are clicked, but to open them when their are clicked with Ctrl key.

Answer (score 3):

You can just insert **C-**(Control), **S-**(Shift) or **M-**(Meta/Alt) in front of your button-number.
So you might use one of the following lines in e.g. `~/.Xresources`

```
! Only execute `launcher` on matched String when using 'Control + Left-Mouse-Button'
URxvt.matcher.button:     C-1
! Only execute `launcher` on matched String when using 'Shift + Middle Mouse-Button'
! URxvt.matcher.button:     S-2
! Only execute `launcher` on matched String when using 'Meta(alt) + Middle Mouse-Button'
! URxvt.matcher.button:     M-2
```

I guess Shift/AltGr is also working when we look at [valid_button](http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/src/perl/matcher?view=markup#l326) in the code but i haven't tried it myself.

And the hover-question i can't answer either. I would guess you would have to change the code a bit.

> I can only recommend something like `URxvt.keysym.C-M-Delete: matcher:select` and just jump around with your Arrow-Keys and choose your *Match*.